# Prioritising what to study over summer

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, advice

After this semester is finished, I plan on studying some more maths over the summer. I’m currently a second year student and my summer is 3 months long. Since this is about the length of 1 full semester, I was thinking of treating it that way.

The books I think I might study are “Topology Without Tears” by Sidney A. Morris, “A first course in abstract algebra” by Fraleigh, “Linear Algebra Done Right” by Axler, and “Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces” by Kristopher Tapp.

This amounts to about 1600 pages, which I could get through at a pace of about 4-5 pages per day (per book).

However, after looking at the Fraleigh book, I realised that it is probably intended to be used for a full year course, and this is likely the same for the other books.

Since, at my university, we usually do 6 modules per semester, it would make sense to eliminate one of these 4 books.

And that is my question: which book should I eliminate?

I’ve done a semester of abstract algebra (covered 50-60% of what is in Fraleigh), already done a year long first course in linear algebra, but have never done differential geometry or topology.

Next year my course includes topology, more abstract algebra, but no differential calculus, and no second course on linear algebra.

I suppose this comes down to whether it is better to study something “extra curricular”, or to get early exposure to material I will learn next year.

Thanks for reading this far, and thanks for any advice

*Edit*: Fixed a calculation

Comment: I suggest self-study of the early chapters of the textbooks for the courses you plan to take in the Fall, but since there's essentially no time pressure, go for depth. Going for depth is a luxury that can't always be achieved when taking classes, so value the opportunity.

Comment: If you do well enough in classes by *taking the classes*, then save your summers for yourself. Explore topics that inspire you and/or pique your curiosity.

Comment: @quasi What exactly does going for depth look like? Is this just attempting proofs before they are presented to you etc?

Comment: @Blue that makes sense to me. So I guess it would make sense to prioritise topics I won’t learn on my course (since I’m interested in all of the topics I mentioned)?

Comment: @Max Allen: By depth I mean a more complete understanding than you would normally have time for when taking the actual class. That would include$\;(1)\;$Working on the harder problems.$\;(2)\;$Asking and attempting to answer questions of your own.$\;(3)\;$Mentally verbalizing the material to the level where you could explain it to someone else (i.e., teach it).

Comment: @quasi oh ok, that seems like a good idea. I’ll do that then. Thanks!